# How to update or add an Environment Variable to a TeamCity agent

Tags: teamcity

TeamCity agent's show a list of "Environment Variables" under Agent Parameters but I cannot get them to update. I've added environment variables to my agent operating system, but cannot get them to refresh. I've tried restarting the agent and disabling and re-enabling the agent.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The TeamCity agent doesn't actually read environment variables from the OS. Instead it reads them from the `buildAgent/conf/buildAgent.properties` file on your agent machine. Down at the bottom of this file you'll see instructions on how to add new variables. Something like this:

```
# Environment Variables
#env.exampleEnvVar=example Env Value
env.GRADLE_HOME=/Frameworks/gradle-2.9
```

Once you've done this, switch to the command prompt on your agent machine, and execute something like this:

```
./agent.sh stop
./agent.sh start
```

Obviously OS dependent. There is a `.bat` file there for Windows.

That should get your environment variables showing up in TeamCity.

Comment: any suggestions for hiding passwords defined this way?

Answer (score 8):

Just tried it in TeamCity 2017.2.1 and the machine-level environment variables are picked up by TeamCity build agents (as well as the ones in buildAgent.properties), so it looks like this has been fixed.

Comment: I will say this didn't seem to be the case on a Linux build agent (version 2018.2.4). Maybe OS specific

Comment: certainly isn't the case for me on Windows build agents... (2020.1.4)